# Netty Message Handler

Tags: java, netty

I am building an application using netty. In the application I need to handle incoming and outgoing messages. The requirement is that any message that the application will send should be handle by a specific handler and any message coming into the application should be handle by another specific handler. However I would like to exchange message between the two handlers to be able to trace sent message response because request messages will also be sent to the application.

Please any idea of hwo to implement such an requirement. The question may sound not relevant but that is what I was given and I am not yet a netty geek. The little I have read about it made me choose it.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Errr.... I'm not clear on your scenario. Could you add a simple box diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

I would outsource this feature to an other layer If I could.
Maybe you could give more details, do you just need to trace the messages ?
When you send a message do you expect a response ?
Can you uniquely identify the message being sent and received ?

Basically I would have an other layer that will always be notified when you send and receive a message.

```
 +--------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                              |
 |                      MessageLoggerHandler                    |
 |                                                              |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------+
              ^                                    +
              +                                    |
 +---------------------------+      +--------------v------------+
 |                           |      |                           |
 |MessageReaderInboundHandler|      |MesageWriterOutboundHandler|
 |                           |      |                           |
 +---------------------------+      +---------------------------+
              ^                                    +
              +                                    |
 +-------------------------------------------------v------------+
 |                                                              |
 |                          NETTY I/O                           |
 |                                                              |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```